# How to add text field on top of the div when the dropdown value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdrop option with in a div. when I select the last option, a text box need to appear on top of the dropdown, when I change the option the text box should disable. How can i do that?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control input-sm" name="opt_change" >
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).find('option:selected').text()` will return you the `text` of the selected `option`

Try this:

```js
$('[name="opt_change"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'Relish') {
    $('#other').show().prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#other').prop('disabled', true);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='other' style='display:none'>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="opt_change">
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** To test last option is selected, use `$(this).find('option:last').prop('selected')` in `if` condition

Comment: maybe better to check if last element is selected instead of comparing the text. if(this).find('option:selected').text() == [lastoption].text()

Comment: @PatrickAleman, I guess test of two options can be identical(_Not logically_) hence I have opted for another solution. I hope it makes sense...

Comment: it does make sense yes

Answer (score 1):

Consider this solution with bootstrap (afais you're using it) and jQuery:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGVQNb

JS:

```
$("div").on("change", "select[name='opt_change']", function() {
  var theLastOption = $("select[name='opt_change'] option:last-child");
  if (theLastOption.is(':selected')) {
    $("#text-box").show();  
  } else {
    $("#text-box").hide();  
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="text-box" class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-1 collapse">
    Hey there! I'm here.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" name="opt_change">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking last option value & selected value like following.

```js
$("select").change(function () {
    var last = $(this).find('option:last').val();
    var sel = $(this).val();

    if (last == sel) {
        var input = $(this).prev('input[type=text]');
        input.length == 0 ? $(this).before('<input type=text />') : input.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(this).prev('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
</div>
```